# Entity framework 6: can't remove many-to-many relationship when relation attributes are specified

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Let's take the following E/R schema:

[image: E/R schema]

and the corresponding EDMX:

[image: EDMX]

Now consider the following data actually in the database:

[image: data sample]

I would like to remove all the legs associated to a given path (ID=4) and so I have to "clear" the many-to-many table... I do the following:

```
var p = _db.Paths.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id == 4);
foreach(var i in p.PathsLegs)
{
   _db.Entry(i).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
}
```

If (like in the proposed data sample) I have a value specified for `IdDestination` and/or `IdInfo` I obtain the following runtime error when calling `SaveChanges()` on the DB context:

> Adding a relationship with an entity which is in the Deleted state is
>   not allowed

If `IdDestination` or `IdInfo` are all NULLs I have no problems at all...

Any ideas? Why is it happening?

Hint: I've already tried to explicitly include referred destination(s)/info(s) in the DB context but with no luck...

---

**EDIT:** I have practically found that setting `Path` and `Leg` to `null` on the entity being deleted prior to marking it as deleted the problem is fixed... but it is still not clear to me the root cause of the problem... which is the connection between the association with `Destination` and/or `Info` and the need to explicitly reset the association with `Path` and `Leg` before removing the entity?

This is the **working** code:

```
var p = _db.Paths.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id == 4);
foreach(var i in p.PathsLegs)
{
   i.Path = null;
   i.Leg = null;
   _db.Entry(i).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
}
```